# Law sines in Spherical Triangle $\rightarrow$ Law sines in plane triangle

Tags: triangles, spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

Could any one tell me how to estimate or get law of sines in Spherical Triangle to The Law of Sines in Plane Triangle? i.e $\frac{\sin a}{\sin  A}=\frac{sin b}{\sin B}=\frac{\sin c}{\sin C}$ to $\frac{ a}{\sin  A}=\frac{ b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}$

Comment: Also posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125440/area-and-sine-rule-of-triangle-on-sphere-and-plane

Answer (score 1):

Make your triangle very small, i.e. almost flat, and use the Approximation $\sin(x)\approx x$.